# Pressable styling doesn't work with native-wind

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css, native, nativewind

I'm using `react-native` with `nativewind` library and conditional styling in `Pressable` doesn't work when it's wrapped in a `View` with `nativewind` classnames. 
So basically removing the `className` from the wrapper `View` make the `Pressable` styling work (background color toggle). 
Why is this happening? :(

```
     <View className="flex-row basis-8/12 gap-x-2">
          <Pressable
            style={({ pressed }) => [
              {
                backgroundColor: pressed ? 'black' : 'white',
              },
            ]}>
            <Text>Select</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
```